# Enable PHP access to folder in windows

Tags: php, apache, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to give access to a php uploader to write uploaded files to folders outside of apache's scope.

- Folder `c` in this case represents the root of Windows Server 2012

The apache folder:

```
/cygdrive/c/apache24  (c:\apache24)
```

The php folder:

```
/cygdrive/c/php
```

The uploader folder:

```
/cygdrive/c/apache24/htdocs/uploader
```

Uploader directive:

```
define('RELATIVE_UPLOAD_DIR', '/cygdrive/c/Users/myusername');
define('UPLOAD_DIR', rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']), '/') . '/' . RELATIVE_UPLOAD_DIR);
```

The uploader will upload files to the uploader's folder, but i am trying to upload files to Windows `Users` folder.

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/myusername
```

How can i enable the `Users` folder and subtree in php.ini so the uploader can write files to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a *Nix environment you would have to make the target directory writable by the apache process owner. If you don't know what that is, take a look in the httpd.conf file. Look for two lines like:

User _www
Group _www

That user must have write access to any target directory. I guess it's just the same in Windows.

I must admit to not liking the idea of writing to user directories though. Might be better to have a rethink on what you are trying to do and find a way to keep userland safe and secure, whilst giving them access to the data.

Comment: all i have is "daemon" but i cant find it in user list when i'm trying to add a principal..

Comment: It is quite possible to get apache to run as anybody you like by changing the User value in that line I posted. You would need to create your own www user on the system and set up apache to run as him/her, then set the relevant permissions. Remember if you do that then you will need to change the ownership of every other place that apache writes to as well and/or the access perms to all the web pages etc. to ensure they are readable. Once you've done all that, restarting apache will change the owner of the process. Not a trivial task but doable if you know what you're doing

Comment: well i think i can manage that, but lets ask differently,i'm basically trying to build multiple uploaders for my dj's (radio station),so instead of creating different uploaders for every dj i have, is there a web based ftp system i can implement on my server? that users just input their user/pass and reach their folders? without a pc/mac client, pure web solution..?

Comment: Ill go with your method for now and look for a more classy solution. thank you

Comment: Doesn't fireftp do something along those lines if it's configured correctly ??

Comment: Can you kindly give me step by step how to do this? I changed the "daemon" to User Tama Group Tama-PC, and create Tama-PC/Tama. I changed the owner the HTTPD to Tama-PC/Tama. But its still not working. Please see http://superuser.com/questions/823017/icacls-on-windows-7-not-working-permission-denied-when-saving-an-image-file?noredirect=1#comment1090036_823017 Thanks